# Subscribe plugin not working

Tags: facebook, plugins, subscribe

So I have a website where I want to put the subscribe button, here is the code

```
<!--FB SUBSCRIBE!-->
<div class="fb-subscribe" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Entendu.info" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial" data-width="50"></div>
```

But when I visit the webpage (www.entendu.info/moderate) On the right where the susbscribe button is suppposed to shoe I got : error and when I click on it :

> The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook user profile, but
>   "http://www.facebook.com/Entendu.info" is not a valid Facebook user
>   profile.
>   [The link of the error](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/api?code=3701&message=The%20%60href%60%20parameter%20must%20reference%20a%20valid%20Facebook%20user%20profile,%20but%20%22http://www.facebook.com/Entendu.info%22%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20Facebook%20user%20profile.&hash=AQCw4k1BLi8FBUTQ)

But the problem is that my url is totally valid ! 
https://www.facebook.com/Entendu.info

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the answer is in the error itself -

> The href parameter must reference a valid Facebook **user profile**, but "http://www.facebook.com/Entendu.info" is not a valid Facebook user profile.

you have to use a valid **user** profile and not the URL of a page.

One can not subscribe to a page in the same way that one can not *like* a person.

You should use a Like button or Like box in your app if you want to add fans to the page.

Comment: @fra - Can't tell if you are being sarcastic or if you are posting questions during class :P

Answer (score 0):

There is a different facebook embed code for PAGES and USERS

To subscribe to a Fan PAGE (usually organizations like cocacola, nike, I used it for participateHW)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

To subscribe to a USER

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/

all the other social plugins are here (just read the description carefully):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/